# Can one specify on a generic type constraint that it must implement a generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-constraints

Here is what I would like to do:

```
public interface IRepository<TSet<TElement>> where TSet<TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>
{
    TSet<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>();
}
```

Is such a construction possible in .NET?

**Edit**: The question was not clear enough. Here is what I want to do, expanded:

```
public class DbRepository : IRepository<DbSet<TElement>> {
    DbSet<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>();
}

public class ObjectRepository : IRepository<ObjectSet<TElement>> {
    ObjectSet<TEntity> GetSet<TEntity>();
}
```

Meaning, I want the constrained type to:
 - accept a single generic parameter
 - implement a given single generic parameter interface.

Is that possible? In fact, I will be happy with only the first thing.

```
public interface IRepository<TGeneric<TElement>> {
    TGeneric<TArgument> GetThing<TArgument>();
}
```

Comment: It is possible but what is the point? If `TSet<TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>` you might as well set the restriction on `IEnumerable<TElement>`.

Comment: @Aliostad: see the edit. I want to set "TElement" only when the function is called, not as a type parameter on the interface.

Comment: Are `Element`s and `Entity`s different things?

Comment: `TElement` is a type argument that is there only to specify that `TSet` is a generic type with one type parameter. `TEntity` is the type argument that is provided when the method `GetSet` is invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use two generic types to achieve this, such as:

```
public interface IRepository<TCollection, TItem> where TCollection : IEnumerable<TItem>
{
    TCollection GetSet<TItem>();  
}
```

(I'm assuming `TEntity` should have been `TElement` in the original...)

That being said, it's most likely better to write something like:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetSet<T>();  
}
```

This would be a more common means of accomplishing the above.

Comment: See the edit: I do not want to set the parameter type for the enumerable at the same time as the interface, but only when the method `GetSet` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, that does not seem to be possible.

I finally worked around that by defining my own interface:

public interface IRepository
{
    IMySet GetSet();
}

And I wrapped both `DbSet` and `ObjectSet` in objects implementing these interfaces.